# Hibernate inheritance query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 4 entities:

`User`, `Teacher`, `Student`, `Course`

and 4 tables:

> t_user, t_teacher_course, t_student_course, t_course

`Teacher` and `Student` extends `User` (with descriminators) and have `@ManyToMany` relationship with `Course` (`User` do NOT have)
`Teacher`'s relations stored in `t_teacher_course` and `Student`'s relations stored in `t_student_course`.

Now i want to select all users with courses (if they exists) in one query
`select u from User u left join fetch u.courses c` (*notice that User do not have courses*)
This select generated something like this:

```
select
    ...
from
    T_USER user0_ 
left outer join
    T_TEACHER_COURSE course1_ 
        on user0_.USERID_=courses1_.TEACHER_ 
left outer join
    T_COURSE course2_ 
        on courses1_.LANE_=course2_.COURSENAME_ 
where
    user0_.GROUP_=?
```

As you can see clearly Hibernate did NOT join with **t_student_course** table

I am using Hibernate 4.1Final

Question: 
Does Hibernate support such queries

a) if supports then why it didn't fetched courses for `Student` entity?

b) if do not support than how can i select all users with their courses using JPQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `u.courses` could be `student.courses` or `teacher.courses`, Hibernate resolves the ambiguity by choosing the first (or last) association with this name in its metadata.

It might work if the name of the `courses` collection is not the same in both subclasses. For example, you could define `Student.attendedCourses` and `Teacher.teachedCourses`.

Otherwise, you'll have to issue two queries (one for teachers and one for students), and join the result lists. Or you'll have to pull up the association in the User entity.

Comment: Uau! Renaming fields solved problem! Thank you very much!
Before your answer i needed to make 3 selects.
I think Hibernate should warn about **ambiguity**